# Why can't I parse YAML with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, yaml

This is my Ruby code:

```
require 'yaml'
yaml = YAML.parse(
  '''
  foo: "hello, world"
  '''
)
puts yaml['foo']
```

I'm getting:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for #<Psych::Nodes::Document:0x007f92a4404d98>
```

It's Ruby 2.1.3

Comment: Just in case you're loading the YAML from a file, take a look at [`YAML.load_file`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.5/libdoc/psych/rdoc/Psych.html#method-c-load_file). Usually we don't have the YAML embedded in a script, but instead either load it from a remote host, in which case `load` is appropriate, or from a file, making `load_file` more convenient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `YAML.load` instead of `YAML.parse` [according to documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML.html#module-YAML-label-Usage) to parse the YAML.

```
require 'yaml'
yaml = YAML.load(
  '''
  foo: "hello, world"
  '''
)
puts yaml['foo']

# => hello, world
```

Comment: RubyMine complains.. I think `load()` is expecting a file name, isn't it?

Comment: @BarbaraKrein in [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML.html#module-YAML-label-Usage) it is a string being provided, not file name. I've just executed this with ruby 2.1.0 in console and it shows no warnings.

Answer (score 4):

What makes you think that you can't parse YAML? The error message says that `Psych::Nodes::Document` doesn't have an `[]` method, and that's true, but the very fact that you got *back* a `Psych::Nodes::Document` object instead of an exception means that the parsing *did* work.

You can read more about how Psych's YAML AST is designed and how it works in the [Psych documentation for `Psych::Nodes`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0_preview2/libdoc/psych/rdoc/Psych/Nodes.html).

Comment: Good point. To access `foo`, use `yaml.to_ruby['foo']` instead of `puts yaml['foo']`.